# Dynamically Assign Routes in ngModule of app.routing.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, dynamic-routing

I have a couple of routes I need to remove based on a flag from a service file. I am not able to set the routes dynamically...Here is what I have tried so far.

My app.routing.module.ts

```
const productionRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'a',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.A),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    }
] as Routes;

const developmentRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'a',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.A),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'b',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.B),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'c',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('module').then(
                (r) => r.C
            )
    }
] as Routes;

export const routes = AppRoutingModule['getRoutes'] // **((("CHANGE HERE")))**;

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
        })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
    constructor(private featureToggleService: FeatureToggleService) {}

    getRoutes(): Routes {
        return this.featureToggleService.productionRoutes()
            ? productionRoutes
            : developmentRoutes;
    }
}
```

As seen above, based on if the boolean returned by productionRoutes(),,I want to dynamically load the routes. Any help here is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Found it, we need to use resetConfig() to reassign the routes in app.component.ts

```
import { developmentRoutes, productionRoutes } from './app.routing.module';

constructor(
    private router: Router
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.hideRoutes =
            this.featureToggleService.productionRoutes();
        this.router.resetConfig(
            this.hideRoutes ? productionRoutes : developmentRoutes
        );
    }
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
export const productionRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'a',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.A),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    }
] as Routes;

export const developmentRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'a',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.A),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'b',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.B),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'c',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import(
                'module'
            ).then((r) => r.C),
        canLoad: [LoginGuard]
    }
] as Routes;

export const routes = productionRoutes;

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
        })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```